# How to select an input by value with jQuery 1.4.3 and higher

Tags: jquery

With jQuery 1.4.2 and many previous version it is possible to select inputs like this:

```
$('input[value=test]')
```

But with 1.4.3 and higher this selector doesn't work =(
Is there any way to select by value in newer versions of jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried `$('input[value="test"]')`? Quotes are mandatory. It will also only work if it matches the `value` attribute in the HTML.

Comment: $('input[value="test"]') doesn't work?

Comment: Can't [confirm](http://jsfiddle.net/DyJRy/)

Comment: [Try](http://jsfiddle.net/VwVhD/) to type 'foo' with 1.2.6, then with 1.4.4

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. In former jQuery versions, inputs value that have been set via JavaScript with the .value property could be selected by attribute selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution is to add this to js:

```
$('input').bind('keyup change',function() {
    $(this).attr('value',this.value)
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/VwVhD/28/

**UPDATE (21.02.2013)**

After years I came up with this actually:

```
jQuery('input,textarea').live('keyup change', function(e) {
    var ignore_codes = [16,9,33,34,36,35,45,38,40,37,39];//arrows and others
    if (e.keyCode && jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, ignore_codes) < 0)//ignore this keyUps to let this keys work as expected
    {
        var cp = getCP(this);
        jQuery(this).attr('value', this.value);
        setCP(this,cp);
    }
    });
    function setCP(ctrl, pos){
        if(ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
            ctrl.focus();
            ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
        } else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
            var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will change the attribute itself, which would break reset button and possibly existing CSS (both unlikely, these days, but possible )

Answer (score 50):

`$('input[value="test"]')` Should work fine...

**EDIT**

You could try using if statements, for example:

```
$("input").keyup(function(e) { 
    if (this.value == 'foo'){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
    }
    else if (this.value == 'bar'){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','green');
    }
    else $(this).css('backgroundColor','white');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/HrXVS/

Comment: hmm... did you click "Update" button after changing jQuery version?

Comment: O! Yep =) Unfortunately selectors in my code comes from another application, so ur way will match for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlexThomas [Obviously you're not a golfer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CWfPUrmeiU).

Answer (score 30):

As far as I can see, in newer jQuery versions, you can select INPUT elements by their "*value*" attribute, but not by the current *.value* property.

When a value is changed by calling *.val()*, changing the native JS *.value* or also by direct user input, the HTML attribute is not changed. In former versions, selectors referred to the current value, while now they correctly refer to the HTML attribute.

You can select however the current value with this code:

```
$('input').filter(function() { return this.value == 'test' });
```

Answer (score 1):

By this code you can select/make checked the input (type radio) by value, which is the same like "for" param in his label.

```
jQuery('label').click(function() {
           labelID = jQuery(this).attr('for'); //find item and save "for" value
           jQuery('input[type=radio][value='+labelID+']').trigger('click') ; // find input with value and click
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it should work just fine

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

you need to use quotes to surround the value