# How do I select an input by it's value after a value is entered using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

See my example below.  I'm trying to enter Mike into the input and then hit "remove input" to remove the input from the page.  It doesn't seem like the value is updated in the DOM when a user types a value.  How can I get around this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMSaD/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439859/how-to-select-an-input-by-value-with-jquery-1-4-3-and-higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is updated in the DOM and you can check this with `alert($('#testing').val());` (`#testing` being the input you wish to remove.)

However `$("input[value='Mike']").remove();` seems to check the value of the HTML attribute as written in the source HTML. Bizarrely, the HTML *attribute* is not updated in this context.

Try this counter intuitive example. Set `value="foo"` on your `#testing` input and type "Mike" into the control at runtime, then:

```
alert($('#testing').attr('value'));    // Mike
alert($('input[value="foo"]').val());  // Mike
```

However, you can force it to update by explicitly assigning to the attribute on change:

```
$('input').bind('change',function() {
    $(this).attr('value',this.value)
});
```

Then your original code will work.

Comment: Kind of a pain that this is required, but it does fix the issue. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#remove").click(function() {
    $("input").filter(function(){
       return this.value === "Mike"
    }).remove()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6pw6/